# How can i insert into table result from another sql statement that returns 2 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables message and user. I would like to insert into the `message` table result from the `users` table which looks like this

```
select id from "user" ORDER BY random() limit 2;
```

And now insert this result instead of:

```
'uuid-from users table',
'uuid-from users table'
```

Insert message query

```
insert into message (id, to_user_id, from_user_id, content)
select uuid_generate_v4(),
'uuid-from users table',
'uuid-from users table',
'Some content';
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
insert into message 
select uuid_generate_v4(), to_user_id, from_user_id, 'Some content' from users;
```

Comment: but to_user/from_user id doesn't exist in the user's table, users table contains an id and username rows. My concern is that i need to insert unique user_id for from/to

Comment: @Andrew what does from_user_id mean?

Comment: it contains id from the user table and it means from which user message was sent

Comment: @Andrew can you use dbfiddle(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14)  share some sample data and also share the desired result. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Here is the example. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d744e4524f342d5bc132e848cabf8f4f

So unique user id, from_user/to_user from users table

Comment: @Andrew Hope this link can solve your problem. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5c763164a99d0bc4641df517887eb5ea

Comment: Awesome thanks! One more question how can i extend this query to use `generate_series` to generate x-amount of data?

Comment: @Andrew https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7a11a34b47eb31a03f731e9631ce54ed